# How to align a dhtml button to the right

Tags: forms, button, dhtml, dhtmlx

I have this button:

{ type:"button", name:"map_button", value:"Show in Map", width: 100, enabled:false  },

what command can I use to align it to the right?  I have tried:

{ type:"button", name:"map_button", align:"right", value:"Show in Map", width: 100, enabled:false  },

and it doesn't work. I am not sure what else it could be

Comment: yes thank you! offsetLeft worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be looking for the "offsetLeft" attribute:

{ type:"button", name:"map_button", offsetLeft:100, value:"Show in Map", width: 100, enabled:false }

Also, you might want to try playing with the "position" attribute as in this link:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/form__positioning.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

> {**type**:'block',**name**:'block_button',**list**:[
>   {**type**:"button", **name**:"map_button",**value**:"Show in
>   Map",**width**:100,**enabled**:false } ]
> }

And after declare the form:

> **name_form**.*_getItemByName*('**block_button**').style.float='right'